# PHP: Get next image using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a comics website which loops through all images in a db and displays them as thumbnails.
The user can click on one of those images to see it in normal size on a viewComic.php template.

I'd like to allow users to press left and right arrows to navigate images.

So, my idea is:

1. pagination.php handles image display on correct pages (by offsetting) by looping through database result array. The user can click on a result (below) to go to that specific image on the viewcomic.php template.

   ```
   '<br />IMG: <a href="./templates/viewcomic.php?id=' . $row['imgid'] . '&image=' . $imgpath.$row['imgname'] . '">
   ```
2. Now on viewcomic.php, I get the id and image, and display the image

   ```
   $imgid = $_GET['id']; 
   $imgpath = $_GET['image']; 
   <center><img src=".<?php echo  $imgpath  ?>" /></center>
   ```

The user can press left and right arrows to navigate through images...
My goal was to somehow increment the image id to move to the next image, but that doesn't seem to be working...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 39) { //get next image           
                <?php 
                    $count = 0;
                    $count++;
                    echo "<img src=" . $imageArray[$count] . "/>";
                ?> 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm going to go through an image array passed in from pagination.php.

So, in my viewcomic.php file, I've updated my jquery script (see above).. but the jquery doesn't seem to like the embedded php, even though it's all in a php file.

Here's a picture of page source vs code:

[image: Page Source]

Comment: I would retrieve the next record using the primary id. Then you know there is a next one, only incrementing is to risky.

Comment: you can pass the list of images in an array and keep going through the array, this way you don't need to refresh the page at each iteration.

Comment: @Ibu I was thinking of doing it that way too. Thanks for the reinforcement :D For some reason, the javascript doesn't seem to work with embedded php... Please see updated question

Comment: @Growler this is not how javascript works. look at the page source and it will make much more sense to you

Comment: @Ibu I know that javascript interacts with the client, and php with the server... but why can I run javascript within php, but not php within javascript? That's confusing me. So, I guess my best bet is to call a php file from the javascript, use php to parse it, then return the result, right?

Comment: @Ibu nevermind, I understand. Php is run first on the server, compiles the page, and sends it to the client, where jscript and html are run after the fact. So, once that page is compiled, you can't run php requests without reloading the page (unless you're using jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i would do:

assuming that an imagepath is surrounded by quotes:

```
echo $imageArray[0]; // 'imagepath/image'
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',',$imageArray) ?>];
// now the image array have the list of all your images. 

$(document).ready(function() {
   var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
   imgIndex = 0;
   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 39) { //get next image           
         img.src = imgArray[imgIndex++]
      }

      ... /* Logic to check if at the end of imageArray */ ...
   });
});
</script>
```

The Html:

```
<center><img src="" id="theImage"/></center>
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by image tag ID? Would this be document.getElementById("<?php $_GET['id'] ?>"); ?

Comment: See my Edit, i added the image tag; this is the image that is going to be changing.

Comment: It's not working. I think the problem is I can't do things like "var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',',$imageArray) ?>]; " because the javascript won't pick up the php.

Comment: run your page on the web browser and show the source code please

Comment: Would e-mailing it to you be easier?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17898/discussion-between-ibu-and-growler)

Comment: I've added a picture of page source vs my source code. Looks like no php is being loaded from javascript.

Comment: I've seen your code, and this is not what it is supposed to do.you cant use an image tag. your $imageArray returns a table. And yes the php code is loaded correctly and doing what it is intended to. you will have to re-evaluate your code. $imgArray is intented to have the image path only and nothing else. but yours have a whole lot of data. How are you populating your array? and please don't add to this thread anymore. if you have any further questions [click here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17898/discussion-between-ibu-and-growler)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 39) { 
       var nextId = $_GET['id'] + 1;
       window.location = "./templates/viewcomic.php?id=" + nextId;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: good idea, but what if he reaches the last id and increments by one?

Comment: that's true.  Ideally, he would have another column in his database that points to the next valid id.  It would be a linked list of sorts

Comment: @TomGerken wow, great idea Tom. Wish I was that creative. I don't have a linked list set up, so I I'm going to go with Ibu's idea of keep going through an image array. For some reason, the javascript doesn't seem to work with embedded php... Please see updated question.

Comment: My mistake- I put int instead of var.  Sorry about that

Comment: @TomGerken Any ideas on why the php won't work within my javascript (code updated above)? Thanks

Comment: Are you running it on a server with PHP installed/  Could you describe what you are experiencing a little more?

Answer (score 0):

In this case your page is submit on every request, You can also handle this at client site.

Click link to see demo about rotate link using JavaScript. : [Link Rotate using javascript](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/p/java-script.html)

Comment: So you're suggesting handle all of this on the client side with Javascript? So, I should pre-load all images from database into a javascript array and just pull from there? What happens when I want to add a new image to the database? I'll still need to request to check if new images need to be added to the javascript array, no?